# Hardware flow control bits not working for ruby-serialport gem

Tags: ruby, serial-port

I am trying to use the control bits of a USB serial port adapter as general purpose I/O. This simple example should toggle the DTR line high, then low.

```
require 'serialport'

DataBits = 8
StopBits = 1
Parity = SerialPort::NONE
Baud = 38400

port = '/dev/tty.usbserial-A100KXWU'

serial = SerialPort.new(port, 'baud' => Baud, 'data_bits' => DataBits, 'stop_bits' => StopBits, 'parity' => Parity)
serial.flow_control = SerialPort::HARD

loop do
    p serial.signals
    sleep(1)
    serial.dtr = (serial.dtr + 1) % 2
end
```

And the output:

```
{"rts"=>1, "dtr"=>1, "cts"=>1, "dsr"=>0, "dcd"=>0, "ri"=>0}
{"rts"=>1, "dtr"=>0, "cts"=>1, "dsr"=>0, "dcd"=>0, "ri"=>0}
{"rts"=>1, "dtr"=>1, "cts"=>1, "dsr"=>0, "dcd"=>0, "ri"=>0}
{"rts"=>1, "dtr"=>0, "cts"=>1, "dsr"=>0, "dcd"=>0, "ri"=>0}
```

As far as Ruby is concerned, `serial.dtr` is changing, but there is no change on the output voltage of the DTR pin. It's a constant +7V.

Additionally, the `serial` instance is unable to *read* any changes applied to CTS, DSR, or DCD coming from other hardware devices.

It is being run with `sudo` privileges, so it's not a issue with permissions. This is on OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

Comment: Let's start from null hypothesis- does your Usb2Serial adapter support controlling/reading those lines? I have seen many adapters that didn't really support full bitbang mode.That's why I dropped such attempts and moved to Usb2Parallel (LPT) adapters which have many more random-accessible lines, that is at least 4+4. But then I got hit by the same issue again - both of my Usb2LPT adapters didn't actually allow to control ALL control/status lines and I could play just with datalines, bummer. So I bought bus pirate (and some chips like [74hc595](https://solarbotics.com/download.php?file=378)) :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, that is a good thought. However, I know the adapter supports reading these lines, because there is other software on Windows that works with this same physical hardware. It's actually a USB-serial chip that is embedded in a piece of radio equipment. I'm in contact with the person who physically designed the boards and the (Windows) software for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. It turns out that Apple's supplied FTDI drivers are buggy. They don't give any access to the control signals.

I installed [the official FTDI VCP drivers](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) (version 2.3 at this time of writing), rebooted, and now I have full control.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/serialport/SerialPort:flow_control=

> Note: SerialPort::HARD uses RTS/CTS handshaking. DSR/DTR is not supported.